# What is the proper way to say the derivate $T:\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R$ of $f$ at $c$ is the tangent plane?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

OK, the post may be long, but this is something haunting in my mind for a long time. Let $c\in E\subseteq \Bbb R^2$, $f:E\to\Bbb R$. If $f$ is differentiable at $c$, then we know that the (total) derivative $T:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$ of $f$ at point $c$ somewhat plays a role as a "tangent plane" of $f$ at $c$. More clearly, the range of $T$, $T(\Bbb R^2)$, which itself is an geometric object in $\Bbb R^3$, is the tangent plane of the graph of $f$ at $c$.

However, to understand it and to explain it to students, there may be several ways. Moreover, there is a crucial point that we shouldn't ignore-- what definition do we adopt, when we using the term *tangent plane*. (in fact, there is another issue here, do we define tangent plane as "*the tangent plane to a function*", or "*the tangent plane to a geometric object in $\Bbb R^n$*", or both?) So my first question is that: what is an ideal/proper definition of them? Recall in elementary calculus course, for pedagogical reasons, these material usually defined for the sake of easiness(so that students can quickly absorb), not requiring too much knowledge. For example, in calculus they tend to define tangent plane as a computational result, but not really define it in terms of a plane $S$ and a geometric object $\Gamma$, and saying that all vectors in $S$ is somewhat really "tangent" to the geometric object $\Gamma$ by some means. However, I somewhat feel that the latter definition might be more formal, closely to the noun "tangent plane", and of mathematician's taste(is it?). Or is there even better way talk about tangent plane? I'm 
 no longer in a freshman stage to learn calculus, so I'm willing to see the "real" terminology and systematic understanding of these things.

The second question depends on the answer of the first one, that is, how do we explain that  the (total) derivative $T:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$ of $f$ at point $c$ somewhat plays a role as a "tangent plane" of $f$ at $c$? The way calculus books explains are usually messy and ugly due to the reason I mentioned. After studying analysis, is there another proper and direct way to explain this?

Comment: The definition used in my differential geometry book (Elementary topics in differential geometry J.A. Thorpe) is: A vector at $p$ is said to be tangent to the level set $f^{-1}(c)$ if it is a velocity vector of a parametrized curve in \matbb{R^n+1} whose image is contained in $f^{-1}(c)$

Comment: @Fightclub1995 Can we talk about a vector at $p$ tangent to an arbitrary object(i.e., not necessarily defined via the preimage of $f$)?

Comment: $f^{-1}(c)$ can be identified as a surface in  $\Bbb R^{n+1}$.

Comment: Maybe one could define it for a manifold?

Comment: @Fightclub1995 Yes, provided one has a differentiable structure on the manifold, that is, an atlas of coordinate charts with $C^1$ transition functions.

Comment: Whatever you do, please make sure your explanation fits the audience.  This is more important than being mathematically precise.

Comment: "the range of $T$, $T(\Bbb R^2)$, which itself is an geometric object in $\Bbb R^3$, is the tangent plane of the graph of $f$ at $c$." No, $T(\Bbb R^2)$ is a subset of $\mathbb R.$ It either equals $\{0\}$ or all of $\mathbb R.$ The set $\{(c,f(c)) + (x,y,T(x,y):(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2\},$ is the plane tangent to the graph of $f$ at $(c,f(c)).$

Comment: @zhw. Thanks! I see.